# Facebook Oauth-enticated users, chat between themselves on website

Tags: facebook, web, oauth, chat

I have a website where users log in with Facebook. Right now there's no way for users to contact each other.

I was thinking of building a dedicated live messenger with sockets, but I wonder if there's an easier way to allow them to send messages to each other's Facebook Messanger, since they are already logged in with facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for a chat between two users. Everything in Messenger API is focused on communication between a user and a page.

At most you can use the Send dialog to let a user send a link to their friends, but that requires the user actively using the button, you can not “automate” that; and handling the result will have nothing to do with your site any more, everything after that will happen in messenger only. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

Comment: Thank you! Custom chat it is then.